# layout:weight on Button change Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I want to make a MediaPlayer and control Play and Pause with the same button.

I did this:

```
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is the layout code for that:

```
<ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />
```

Everything works fine except the fact that the button Pause shows up and it keeps its full size, the

> android:layout_weight=".33"
>   command doesn't apply on it.

What is the problem? and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure that button resizes, not the inside image forces to resize it. try setting the content mode of ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seem that you changed the background image instead of the image of ImageView.
You may try:

1. setImageResource instead of setBackgroundResource (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))
2. add  android:scaleType="centerInside" to ImageView xml
3. change to android:layout_width="0dp"

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
    mediaPlayer.start();
    buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
}else {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
}
```